# Why Am I Getting Link Errors When Calling Function in Math.h?

Tags: math, gcc, linker

When attempting to call functions in `math.h`, I'm getting link errors like the following

```
undefined reference to sqrt
```

But I'm doing a `#include <math.h>`
I'm using gcc and compiling as follows:

```
gcc -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE blah.c -o blah
```

Why can't the linker find the definition for `sqrt`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add -lm to the command when you call gcc:
gcc -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE blah.c -o blah -lm

This will tell the linker to link with the math library.  Including math.h will tell the compiler that the math functions like sqrt() exist, but they are defined in a separate library, which the linker needs to pack with your executable.

As FreeMemory pointed out the library is called libm.a .  On Unix-like systems, the rule for naming libraries is lib[blah].a .  Then if you want to link them to your executable you use -l[blah] .

Comment: Actually, if you do that on a modern Linux system, you will end up linking to libm.so, which is the dynamic library equivalent of libm.a.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link the math library explicitly. Add `-lm` to the flags you're passing to gcc so that the linker knows to link `libm.a`

Comment: You know, you can fix it, right? :)  You can always edit your answers and questions.

Answer (score 2):

Append `-lm` to the end of the gcc command to link the math library:

```
gcc -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE blah.c -o blah -lm
```

For things to be linked properly, the order of the compiler flags matters! Specifically, the `-lm` should be placed [at the end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344445/undefined-reference-to-pow-even-with-math-h-and-the-library-link-lm).

If you're wondering why the `math.h` library needs to be included at all when compiling in C, check out this explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c).