# a gcc sqrt function bug?

Tags: c, gcc

The following program cannot compile in gcc. But it compiles OK with g++ and MSC++ with `.c` extension.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double t = 10;
  double t2 = 200;

  printf("%lf\n", sqrt(t*t2));

  return 0;
}
```

My system is CentOS, the version info.

```
> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The error info:

```
> gcc test.c
/tmp/ccyY3Hiw.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this a bug?

Any one can do a test for me?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you linked the math library?

```
gcc -lm test.c -o test
```

Comment: Because `g++` pulls in `-lstdc++` which pulls in `-lm`.

Comment: You don't want to compile 'raw' C code with `g++`.  C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: The gcc I use requires the `-lm` *after* test.c (4.6.1 on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Try `gcc -lm test.c -o test`

For gcc, you need to tell it to link the math library in, by adding -lm
to your gcc call.

Answer (score 2):

Add the math library with flag `-lm`

```
> gcc test.c -lm
```

Answer (score 2):

Everybody has been saying this, but I will too.  You have to "tell" gcc to link to the math library. When you compile, instead of saying `gcc test.c`, you have to say `gcc -lm test.c`.  I wish that I could just `#include` math.h and not have to do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is,   `gcc -lm test.c -o test`  won't work because gcc will treat the -lm as a compiler and not a linker option.  You need to put the -lm at the end of the command instead, i.e.    `gcc -o test test.c -lm`