# Linking include files in GCC

Tags: gcc

I can never remember what to type when linking include files in GCC, in fact the only one I can remember is `-lm` for `math.h`.  The one I am specifically concerned with right now is `sys/time.h`.

[This page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html) clears things up some, but I would still like a list.

Does anyone know of a good list of linking options?

**EDIT:**

Maybe my question was not clear.  I want to know what I need to type at the command line (like `-lm` for math or `-lpthread` for pthread) for the various libraries I might need to link when making C programs.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality provided in `<sys/time.h>` is implemented in `libc.so` (C library). You don't need to link anything else in as gcc should automatically link to `libc.so` by itself. There is no 'linking of include files', rather you are linking against libraries that contain the symbols defined by code.

The `-l` flag is one of [GCC's linker options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) and is used to specify additional libraries to link against.

**edit because my gcc was performing optimizations on my source code at compile time**

<strike>Also, the information in that link is a little outdated - you should not need an explicit link to `libm` (which is what `-l m` or `-lm` does) in modern GCC.</strike>

Comment: Wow, when did that happen?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c/1033940#1033940  I'm pretty sure that was accurate a year ago…

Comment: @ephemient - `libstdc++` still links to `libm.so` on my system (With G++ 4.4.5), but I meant that you shouldn't need the `-lm` flag to pull it in at all with C code.

Comment: I'm just wondering when that changed.  Testing with GCC 4.2.4, 4.3.5, 4.4.3, 4.4.5, and 4.5.1, along with glibc 2.11.1 and 2.12.1, I still need `-lm` for plain `gcc`.  Which modern GCC do you mean?

Comment: @ephemient - I'm using GCC 4.4.5 on Debian 5- it might just be a quirk with my version. I compiled C code using a bunch of the `math.h` functions, and compiled with just `gcc source.c`. I just tested on an RH5 machine with gcc 4.1.2 and it requires `-lm`. Time to edit my answer.

Comment: I wonder if it's architecture dependent.  I've tested on 3 x86_64 machines: Gentoo, Debian sid (which comes with glibc 2.11.2, I miscounted in my earlier comment), Ubuntu Lucid.  Also, are you sure you're actually linking the math functions?  GCC's constant folding will fold the math functions too.

Comment: @ephemient - that was it - gcc's floating point constants folding was the problem. If I compile with `gcc -frounding-math source.c` I get undefined reference errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question but -lm is not an ld **option**, -l is an option and -lx links libx.a (or .so, it depends). you might want to look at the ld manual for a full list of options.

I think all other standard libraries other than math are included in libc.so(.a) (-lc)

Comment: `libcrypt`, `libdl`, `libpthread`, `libresolv`, and `librt` all contain more standard C/POSIX functions that aren't in `libc` and `libm`.  Many people would consider `libz` to be a standard system library too.