# gcc: why is the -lm flag needed to link the math library?

Tags: gcc, libc

I just discovered that the `-lm` flag is needed by gcc in order to compile a program that refers a function from the math library. I'm wondering why an explicit linking flag isn't needed when compiling programs containing other libraries such as the time library. If I write a program where the `time()` function is called, it would compile with no problems even with no linking options. But a program with the math library involved just won't work without the `-lm` flag.

Can anyone please explain the reason behind this behaviour? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Weird historical reasons, but mostly because It's How It Is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c