# Makefile: undefined reference to acos

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I've done some research on this issue and have included `-lm` at the end of my list of tags, but I keep getting an undefined reference to ____ with several math functions like `cos` and `sin`.

Edit: I included <math.h>,<stdlib.h>,<stdio.h>

```
CFLAGS= -std=gnu18 -Wall -Wextra -Who-unused -pedantic -g -O3 -lm
CC=gcc
PROGRAMS=main
LIBS=libct.a
OBJECTS= mex.o count.o id.o orag.o
all: $(PROGRAMS) $(LIBS)
libct.a: $(OBJECTS)
        ar rcs $@ $^
main: main.o $(OBJECTS)
%.o: %.c
     $$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
%: %.o 
     $$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
.PHONY:clean_objects clean all
clean_objects:
        rm -f *.o
clean:
        rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(LIBS) *.o
```

Comment: it would help if you posted the code.

Comment: Maybe you forget to include <math.h> in your source file

Comment: I included <math.h> in all my files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We require that a question of the form *"why doesn't this code work"* include a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That's not just for our benefit; it's a vital coding skill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you need an explicit \`-lm\` compiler option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371647/why-do-you-need-an-explicit-lm-compiler-option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker will not link `libm` unless you specify it after object files that use it. So you need to change to

```
LDFLAGS = -lm
```

and

```
%: %.o 
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: As such, not overriding the built-in recipe for `%: %.o` is probably a better fix.