# command line prompt command (want to understand what its doing)

Tags: c, command-line, cs50

I am doing the CS50 class, I have installed the cs50.h.
Based on the  [instructions](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/installing-cs50-h-on-a-mac) I used the following command in terminal to compile my simple program and just want to make sure I understand everything im asking terminal to do.
Line is:

```
gcc -g hello.c -o hello -lcs50 -lm
```

I know the following*: gcc =

- gcc = gnu compiler for C
- -g = generate source-level debug information
- Hello.c = name of the file we want to compile
- -o = write output file
- hello = our output file name

Can anyone tell me what -lcs50 and -lm are? My guess is that its calling on the library lcs50 in (-lcs50) but again this is a guess and would like to know for sure.

Everything works as it should with no issues

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly correct.

- `-o` is not required to generate the output file, it's only needed to customize the name. (`-o` and the following name can only appear together).
- `-lcs50` means "link the library called `cs50`", not `lcs50`. It will try to find this file using several different name patterns, e.g. `libcs50.so` (on Linux), `[lib]cs50.dll[.a]` (on Windows), `libcs50.a` (on both), something else on Mac.
- `-lm` links the standard math library, but I don't think you need to manually specify it on most modern GCC distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For -lm, it's for the maths library, which is not linked by default. This is explained well at [Why do you need an explicit `-lm` compiler option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371647/why-do-you-need-an-explicit-lm-compiler-option).

Comment: Thank you! So then is my assumption right that -lcs50 is just the library I am calling on so that #include <cs50.h> works in my code?

Comment: Yes (assuming that I've understood the purpose of ``cs50.h`` correctly).