# Using math.h sqrt function in C

Tags: c, unix, math, sqrt

Reading the documentation for math.h, it seems like all I should have to do is include math.h, and use the math functions included, such as sqrt.  The problem is I get the following error when trying to use sqrt in my program.  I tried math.sqrt, but that did not work, either.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a, b;

  a = 1;
  b = 5;

  if (a < sqrt (b))
    printf("1 < sqrt(5)");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe use `-lm` option

Comment: I know it says `sin`, but it's the same for any math function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitely *link* with the math library as `sqrt` depends on it. Retry with appending `-lm` to your compilation line :

```
gcc you_file.c -o my_sqrt -lm
```

Comment: Why does this library need to be explicitely linked when others don't?

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606301/gcc-why-the-lm-flag-is-needed-to-link-the-math-library