# Unable to link Embarcadero XE4 project when using floorf() function

Tags: c++, c, math, linker-errors, c++builder-xe4

I need to use the floorf() function defined in Math.h and while I can compile the module where this is used successfully in my XE4 project, I receive this error when linking:

> ```
> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_floorf' referenced from <myfilename>.OBJ
> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
> ```

This makes no sense - the compiler obviously knows where the function is declared as it opens Math.h when I control-click on the floorf() function. and I've included #include  in the .cpp file. What do I need to get this working? I really need to use this standard math function.

Comment: Adding the header file only makes the compiler aware of the prototype for the function; it doesn't tell the linker where to find it. You need to include the math library as well.

Comment: have you included the library (not header file)  that contains the 'floorf' function.  BTW: the function name is 'floorf' not '_floorf'

Comment: I cannot figure out what the name of the library to include is. I've tried both math.lib and libm.lib both of which apparently don't exist. How am I supposed to magically know the name of the lib file when it's different from the header and never documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Linking with math library is not enabled by default in some compilers.

[gcc: why the -lm flag is needed to link the math library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606301/gcc-why-the-lm-flag-is-needed-to-link-the-math-library)

Comment: Understood, but I've never heard of such behavior with Embarcadero C++ Builder (any version). If there's a setting I need to use to enable this, I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Isaac borland/embarcadero compilers add linkage to math when you include math.h/math.hpp no switch is needed. it is usually done by `#pragma link "blablabla.obj"` line inside header file ...

Answer (score 0):

I use BDS2006 so this may not help but:

1. try to use `floor()` instead of `floorf()`

   - if you have ambiguility problems use `float(floor(float(x)));`
2. try to include  instead of  or the other way around to see if it helps
3. do you use any namespace? (try to use `::floor()`)
4. didn't you forget some `;`,`{`,`}`,`};` ? especially in `struct`/`class`/`namespace`
5. do you use `#define`s ?

   - borland/embarcadero has sometimes problems with code inside defines
   - very rarely it compile it wrongly so the code does not work as it is written
   - did see this few times usually swapping/inserting  some lines (even empty) helps
6. where do you use the floorf function (cpp file or unit or form)?

   - if you add unit file to the project (with your own stuff not Window/Form code)
   - then it is presumed to be VCL/machine generated stuff like Form not standard C/C++ file
   - and it is compiled/linked differently
   - if this is the case remove the file from project
   - and add include of it to one of the Form cpp/h files where it is needed
   - I saw this behavior in BCB5,BCB6,BDS2006
7. do you use some `#define`s that collide with math internal compilation tokens?

   - some defines could be used internally to enable//disable parts of code inside math
   - so if you define the same prior to math include you can mess with it
   - do not use tokens like `_math`,`_floor`...
8. how do you name your own functions

   - if they collide with **VCL** names then weird stuff starts to happen
   - the typical is own `Draw()` functions with collision with internal `TForm::Draw`
   - no bug is reported but sometimes the code does not work (even if call operands are not the same)
   - last saw this on BCB6
   - just rename those to `draw()` and you will be fine unless you are bound to some naming scheme

My bet is the point 6 saw it many many times back in my teaching times