# How to get absolute value for a double value within a function (Without using math.h)

Tags: c, math, double, absolute, arithmetic-expressions

how can I get absolute value for the double diff in this case?

```
double cos_delta(double x, double delta)
 {
int n = 1;   // n should start with 1 because it is the number of terms

double diff = cos_N(x, n ) - cos_N(x, n - 1);  // n and n-1 instead of n-1 and n-2

********* here ************

while (diff > delta) { // fabs returns absolute value of a double

    n++;
    diff = cos_N(x, n ) - cos_N(x, n - 1);
}
printf("n = %d\n", n);
return cos_N(x, n);
```

}

Comment: Why without using `math.h`?

Comment: because i'm not able to use it in this program

Comment: this is not a question, answer is too easy to ask here: `double abs(double i) { return i < 0? -i: i; }`

Comment: but in C, as far as I know, you can't use a faction within a function! I know these kinda questions are easy for you guys, but i'm trying to learn

Comment: Huh?   What do you mean by "can't use a faction within a function"?   And how is that relevant to your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use a function within a function"?  You shouldn't define functions within other functions, though GCC allows it as an extension.  You can call other functions from within a function though.  And creating a simple `static inline double abs_dbl(double x) { return (x < 0.0) ? -x : x); }` seems pretty straight-forward.  (Note that `abs()` is an integer function defined in `<stdlib.h>`; it's why the standard function for `double` is `fabs()` and not `abs()` — we don't have `fcos()` (though there is `cosf()`, but that's a separate discussion.)

Comment: why are you not able to use it? If there's no math.h that's not a C compiler. If you use gcc [you must specify `-lm`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4606301/995714)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the comparison and put the result (In case of negative double value prepend it with unary `-` (unary minus) else the value is positive).

Using a simple `if` statement will be best way to deal with this.

```
if( dblVal < 0 )
   dblVal =  -dblval;
```

or you can make a function and use it like this

```
double myabs(double d){
    if( d < 0 )
      return -d;
    return d;
}
```

But it is always better to use the math library functions `fabs()` etc.

Comment: If this is what I think I'm looking at he'll get link errors calling `fabs()`. If he's building up a `cos()` power series the hard way he obviously can't call `cos()` so I don't think `fabs()` is there either. On the other hand you did answer his question quite well.

Comment: @Joshua.: Thanks for passing by and reading the answer. Anu suggestions or edit in the answer is highly appreciated. Thanks.