# How can I include a needed C library using GCC?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, indicator

I am trying to compile the simple C example from [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Typical%20usage%20%28C%20version%29) on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) using GCC. What do I have to use as arguments for GCC to include the needed libraries for `#include <libappindicator/app-indicator.h>`?

Comment: Related: *[What is the meaning of -lm in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175151/what-is-the-meaning-of-lm-in-gcc)*, *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)*, and *[GCC -lm -lz -lrt options - what are they about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663097/gcc-lm-lz-lrt-options-what-are-they-about)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used `apt-get`, `Synaptic Package Manager`, etc. to get the `appindicator` library (vs. building it from source), did you only install the `libappindicator1` package or did you *also* install `libappindicator-dev` to get the `libappindicator` header files?  Linux packages very often have split the runtime libraries from the compile-time headers.  That way people who only need the libraries to satisfy a dynamic link don't have to install unneeded headers.  But since you're doing development you need those headers and therefore need the `libappindicator-dev` package as well.

Comment: I added the libappindictaor-dev package. What do I have to use with gcc as -l argument?

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/natty/i386/libappindicator-dev/filelist you need to use `-I/usr/include/libappindicator-0.1/libappindicator`

Answer (score 98):

```
-I<search path to include files>
-L<search path to the lib file>
-l<libname>
```

Comment: indeed @debuti ... furthermore, seems that one can omit the space between the `I` or `L` and the `searchpath`, and put it all together like: `-I<searchpath to include files>`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, only regurgitating the (incomplete) documentation. A proper answer would at least address possible ***naming conventions*** used to derived the actual argument. What should the actual argument be? `-llibappindicator`? `-lappindicator`? Something else?

Answer (score 19):

Use the `-l` command line option. You can specify the library search path with the `-L` option. E.g:

```
gcc -o myprogram -lfoo -L/home/me/foo/lib myprogram.c
```

This will link `myprogram` with the static library `libfoo.a` in the folder `/home/me/foo/lib`.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, only regurgitating the  (incomplete) documentation. A proper answer would at least address possible ***naming conventions*** used to derived the actual argument. What should the actual argument be? `-llibappindicator`? `-lappindicator`? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen How can I find the answer for this? I wonder why I need use `-L/path/to/libname` but `-lname`.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
gcc example.c -o example  `pkg-config --cflags --libs appindicator-0.1`
```

*pkg-config* will fetch the required include and library flags for `libappindicator` and its dependencies. This assumes `libappindictaor-dev` package is already installed.

Comment: What is supposed to happen by that command line invocation? How do those backticklies work? Is there some exchange using [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)? Or not? In general, why is this necessary? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12686188/edit), not here in comments (**** ***without*** **** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 6):

What I do is:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep indicator
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7320100/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Is it a response to [manugupt1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-can-i-include-a-needed-c-library-using-gcc/6017057#6017057)?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) app, and the previous solutions are as applicable anywhere like using the [-l](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l) option and [-I](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-I) option,

However, for GTK applications, you may also use *[pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config)* which makes it easier as your paths can be predefined.

An interesting example can be found in
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-compiling.html

Comment: The last link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

The default path for all c++ include files like library files and header files  in ubuntu/linux are found in `/usr/include/c++/11`