# Compiling a C program issue in the terminal

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a C program in the terminal.

This is my command:

```
gcc -1 string -o syncing.c -o syncing
```

This is my result:

```
clang: error: no input files
```

I know that `-1`... indicates the library I used, `syncing.c` is the C file I am trying to compile.

What am I doing wrong with my command or is it something else?

I am only using standard libraries.

Comment: The error message indicates [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), not [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (`"clang: error: no input files"`). It is apparently common to [alias the executable `gcc` to the Clang compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-error-when-using-gcc-compile-option-werror#comment131019685_38840601) or frontend.

Comment: What system, setup, or even educational institution or system make it common to alias the executable "`gcc`" to the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler? For instance, is it some common "distribution" of Clang or software where Clang is a part of it? For instance, could it be Python/[Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) that also installs a compiler, effectively "overwriting" the existing "`gcc`" executable?

Comment: Starting points (but it ***isn't*** on any of those): *[Clang command line argument reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)*, *[index of options, etc.](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/genindex.html)*, *[Diagnostic flags in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wreturn-stack-address)*, and *[Clang man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/clang)*.

Comment: Here is a hint regarding the aliasing of executable `gcc` to the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler: *[Why does the `gcc` command on macOS execute `clang`?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-gcc-command-on-MacOS-execute-clang?share=1)*. Due to [licensing issues](https://www.quora.com/Is-Apple-supporting-Clang-in-order-to-destroy-GCC/answer/Mario-Ray-Mahardhika-1)?

Comment: Is `-1` (the number) a typo of `l` (the letter)? Under *"Linker flags"* on *"[Clang command line argument reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)"* there is [-l](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-l-arg) ("l" as in [lowercase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lowercase#Adjective), not the number). Would that make sense in a Clang context?

Comment: Trying this on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) (yes, I know) with Clang 6.0.0 results in the ***same*** last error "`clang: error: no input files"`. But also in the error line "`clang: error: unknown argument: '-1'`".

Comment: Use of the word *"terminal"* may also hint at Mac: the proper noun (or whatever it is called) "[Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal)", a macOS application. (Though it is also *"GNOME Terminal"*.) But perhaps it would be more likely that "command-line" was used instead(?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read up on [how to use GCC](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+gcc&hl=en), [GCC command-line options](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+command+line+options&hl=en) and also [official command-line documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You are telling it that `syncing.c` is your output file. But you want it to be your input file.

Also, I am not so sure on the `-1` there. You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc) on how to include/link external libraries. [Here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html) are more examples on that.

You probably meant something like:

```bash
gcc syncing.c -lstring -o syncing
```

Comment: The first link is weird. Opening it results in the browser prompting for a file location, not opening it as a normal HTML page (the content is actually HTML). At least in Firefox 106.0.2 (*"[Always ask you where to save files](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/29/setting-up-firefox-on-a-new-system/)"* is enabled, but that shouldn't really matter for *.html* files). E.g., is there a special character in the file part of the URL?

Comment: *[https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/)* opens normally.

Comment: Is the web server sending something weird?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the feedback. After 9 years, documentation has evolved. I added some hopefully slightly more future-proof links now. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks. Though, looking at the question again, it is probably [not about GCC, but Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296282/compiling-a-c-program-issue-in-the-terminal/20296301#comment131282271_20296282).

Comment: -1 [could be a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296282/compiling-a-c-program-issue-in-the-terminal/20296301#comment131285580_20296282).

Comment: What is the correct command line, then? Incl. the two fixes?