# Difference between a straight 'gcc' compile and 'gcc -lm -Wall -o'

Tags: c, clang

I am working on a homework assignment for my computer science class and, we are required to develop this simple program for our first use of C.

I was able to create the program through a straight `gcc` compile, but while using `gcc -lm -Wall -o` compile, my program crashes and returns

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What would cause my program to crash when entering it into the second compile?

#### My code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    float enrollment, fullsec, leftover, receiveA, receiveB, receiveC, receiveD;
    printf("Program #1, masc0865, Tom Bachar");
    printf("Enter enrollments on one line: ");
    scanf("%f", &enrollment);
    fullsec = enrollment/25;
    leftover = enrollment%25;
    printf("Enrollment = %f", enrollment);
    printf("Amount of Full Sections = %f", fullsec);
    printf("Students Left Over = %0.2f", leftover);
    receiveA = enrollment*0.30;
    receiveB = enrollment*0.25;
    receiveC = enrollment*0.15;
    receiveD = enrollment*0.30;
    printf("Students expected to receive an A: %f", receiveA);
    printf("Students expected to receive a B: %f", receiveB);
    printf("Students expected to receive a C: %f", receiveC);
    printf("Students expected to receive some other grade: %f", receiveD);
}
```

Comment: the "gcc -lm -Wall -o" command is the compile that  the teacher will use to compile our program as documented in our handout.

Comment: Please show the code which you are compiling.

Comment: @marscher: `-lm` is using the `-l` flag in gcc, and is passing it the `m` argument. Together this means to link against `libm.so`, otherwise known as the math library.

Comment: @sharth: try invoking gcc -lm without any further arguments

Comment: @marscher: I understand that if Sherman didn't pass any source files, that this is a reasonable output. But `-lm` is a valid argument to gcc. And it's documented.

Comment: @sharth all i type in is gcc -lm -Wall -o ./a.out

Comment: @marscher I tried just passing in gcc -lm and it returned "ld: can't link with a main executable file './a.out' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @ShermanBachar You still aren't sending it the actual *source file*, though. For example, if your code is in `homework.c`, use `gcc -lm -Wall -o a.out homework.c` (I think that's the right order).

Comment: @Chris Hayes So what I do is go into the file where my code is (classgrades.c) and I compile it with the code gcc -lm -Wall -o  homework.c but I get the same return and the file disappears!

Comment: @ShermanBachar: __No!__ If your source file is `classgrades.c`, and you'd like it to produce an executable named `a.out`, then you would do: `gcc -lm -Wall -o a.out classgrades.c`. The argument after `-o` will be __overwritten__.

Comment: Change `void main()` to `int main()` and add `return 0;` as the last statement; it won't solve the error but it will reduce a warning.

Comment: `leftover= (int)enrollment%25;` should fix the error.

Comment: @ShermanBachar You need **both** the output file name and the input file. See my answer for details (or the comments and the other answer).

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).

Comment: For `-lm`, see *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)* (18 answers. 314 upvotes. 2009.)

Comment: But it says "`clang:`". Is the executable `gcc` aliased to the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler executable (***not*** [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection))? That [wouldn't be the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-error-when-using-gcc-compile-option-werror#comment131019685_38840601)....

Comment: What common environment or tool aliases executable `gcc` to the Clang compiler?

Comment: Note: the code was added in revision 3, but unexplained removed in revision 7.

Comment: For leaving out the source file (as correctly identified in [Bill Lynch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829950/difference-between-a-straight-gcc-compile-and-gcc-lm-wall-o/25830031#25830031)), I can't reproduce the first lines, but using the Clang 6.0.0 compiler on Linux gives the exact same last line: *"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"*. Whereas using a (real) GCC compiler/frontend (7.5.0) gives a very different result: *"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"*

Comment: Thus, I think we can conclude the OP (effectively) used some version of the Clang compiler (but with the frontend/executable name `gcc`), not GCC.

Comment: (Why do compilers have to be so cryptic? Couldn't they just report *"Missing input file(s)."*)

Comment: Conclusion: This is for [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), ***not*** [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) ("`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`"). This is likely on a Mac [where executable 'gcc' is aliased to the Clang compiler](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-gcc-command-on-MacOS-execute-clang). The underlying reason [may be GPLv3](https://www.quora.com/Is-Apple-supporting-Clang-in-order-to-destroy-GCC/answer/Mario-Ray-Mahardhika-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compile your code with gcc, you also need to pass in the names of your source files. So if you had a source file named `project1.c`, you could compile it by running:

```
gcc -lm -Wall -o a.out project1.c
```

Assuming your code successfully compiled (no errors), you could run it by then doing:

```
./a.out
```

That being said, your code won't compile. You can't use the modulus operator against a floating point number.

```
foo.c:9:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')
    leftover= enrollment%25;
              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i fix this float issue?

Comment: @ShermanBachar: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, which makes it hard to suggest a fix.

Comment: @ShermanBachar Is there a reason you are using `float` rather than `int` or `double`? The most obvious fix seems to be using `int` where appropriate.

Comment: Libraries after object files, at least for reliable linking.

Comment: It doesn't change the fix, but [the OP used the Clang compiler, not GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829950/difference-between-a-straight-gcc-compile-and-gcc-lm-wall-o/25830031#comment131087032_25829950).

Comment: `a.out` is the default for `gcc` and `clang` when you do not specify the output file; this could be simplified by omitting the `-o a.out`, but usually you would specify the target output.

Answer (score 1):

To learn about the command line arguments for `gcc`, you can use the [man page for `gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

```
man gcc
```

The documentation is very daunting because there are a lot of options. Some experience with man pages will help you quickly scan for the information you need.

The first thing to look at is the *SYNOPSIS* section at the top. This shows the usage of `gcc`. Anything in `[]` is optional. Note at the very end of this section, there is `infile...`. This means that you **must** provide at least one file name for the compiler to process. I suspect you are getting an error because you are missing this.

So the correct command line should be

```
gcc -Wall -o <program> <program>.c -lm
```

This will compile your `.c` file to an executable with the same name without an extension.

For details about the options you are using, the following comes directly from the `gcc` man page.

```
-Wall

    This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users
    consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
    prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros.

-llibrary
-l library
    Search the library named library when linking.

-o file
    Write output to file.
```

The errors you get are due to the `-Wall` option.

The `-lm` flag links in a library named "m". This is a math library which you probably don't need to worry about for now. For more details about this library use `man libm`.

Note that the `-o` option requires an argument. In your case, this tells `gcc` the name of the executable to create. (This is the reason for `-o <program>` in my suggested solution above.)

Comment: thanks for the awesome in depth answer, I edited my initial post to include the code I am working with.

Comment: @ShermanBachar I have made an edit to give you a suggested solution to your problem.

Comment: The errors aren't caused by `-Wall`, that's only if you compile with `-Werror`.

Comment: @Sherman - looking at your code I see no immediate error.  However, as Code-Apprentice suggests you invocation of the compiler seems to be in error.  I would be interested in seeing the output of you trying the command he suggests.

Comment: Libraries after object files — at least for reliable linking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In this case, I assume you mean "libraries after **source** files", correct? Since we are compiling and linking in a single step, the object files are not given explicitly on the command-line, of course.

Comment: Well, yes, and no, but mainly yes.  Yes, put the `-lm` after the source files in the C compiler command line; that gets translated by the compiler into libraries after the object files in the linker command line.

Comment: [It ***isn't*** GCC, but Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829950/difference-between-a-straight-gcc-compile-and-gcc-lm-wall-o?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment131286752_25829950). The name of the executable is `gcc`, but it is on a Mac with executable `gcc` aliased to the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler... There are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-e#comment131284665_38840601) [of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296282/compiling-a-c#comment131285788_20296282) kind of questions (most mistagged as GCC).

Comment: @PeterMortensen The OP does not mention which OS they are on, so I think it is not valid to make any assumptions about what is aliased or not.