# How can I ignore an error when using GCC compile option '-Werror'?

Tags: c, clang

I have the following test code, file *test.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *func()
{
    int i = 123;
    return &i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", *func());
}
```

If I use the command to compile it that is OK,

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

It will have the following warning information:

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'i'
  returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
return &i;
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

But it can output the result: `123`

If I use the command:

```
gcc -Werror test.c -o test
```

It will have the following error information:

```
error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'i'
  returned [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
return &i;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Now I want to use the *[-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)* option, but I also want to ignore the *address of stack memory associated with local variable 'i'* warning. What should I do?

Comment: You realize that returning a pointer to stack variables is a terrible idea, right? If you make any function calls at all (including implicit function calls, sometimes performed when you initialize a struct/array with `= {0};` for instance), the value referenced by the pointer will no longer be valid. This is a warning for a reason.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger I got it, I only want to resolve it temporary.

Comment: Some canonicals for the error you can not ignore - as said in an answer (what is the point of getting rid of a warning if the result is almost certainly a crash at runtime?):

Comment: Same error message: *[Using C-string gives Warning: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041100/using-c-string-gives-warning-address-of-stack-memory-associated-with-local-var)*

Comment: *[C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)* (2011, five answers and 137 upvotes).

Comment: *[Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/)* (2012, 12 answers, and 196 upvotes)

Comment: The result is different in newer versions of GCC. Both 7.5.0 (7.4 released 2018-12-06)  and 9.4 (released 2021-06-01): `warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]`. For `&` in `return &i;`. It was tested on Linux / Ubuntu ([18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) and [20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa))).

Comment: What version of GCC? Running on what platform?

Comment: ***I don't think the OP has used [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)***, but [rather Clang instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-error-when-using-gcc-compile-option-werror/38840652#comment130977715_38840652). [`-Wreturn-stack-address`](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/clang/warnings-clang-3.3.txt) is a characteristic of [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang). It does not exist in GCC (unless it was removed before GCC 3.4 (2003 or earlier) - very unlikely).

Comment: The result with [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) version 6.0 on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) was the *exact* same as reported in the question.

Comment: The result with [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) version 6.0 on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) was the *exact* same as reported in the question: `clang SO38840601.c -o test`. Perhaps `gcc` is an alias to `clang` on the OP's system? Is that a common thing?

Comment: [A documentation entry](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wreturn-stack-address) for "-Wreturn-stack-address" in Clang.

Comment: Another signature of Clang is *"1 warning generated."* (GCC doesn't output anything in that regard). This is strengthened by the output for the `-Werror` case:  Clang outputs "`1 error generated`" whereas GCC outputs "`cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`".

Comment: I think we can conclude the OP had the executable `gcc` aliased (or similar) to the executable for the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler (most likely the executable `clang`).

Comment: (Actually using GCC (version 7.5.0) to compile the program (without '-Werror'), and [on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29), running it resulted in *"`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`"*.)

Comment: Here is a hint regarding the aliasing of executable `gcc` to the [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler: *[Why does the `gcc` command on macOS execute `clang`?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-gcc-command-on-MacOS-execute-clang?share=1)*. Due to [licensing issues](https://www.quora.com/Is-Apple-supporting-Clang-in-order-to-destroy-GCC/answer/Mario-Ray-Mahardhika-1)?

Comment: Was it on a Mac?

Comment: What was your platform (e.g., Linux distribution, incl. versions) and configuration (e.g. of compilers, incl. versions)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most `gcc` warnings can be disabled by prefixing the name of the warning with `no-`, e.g. `-Wno-return-stack-address`.

That said, this is not something you want to ignore; returning pointers to stack variables is undefined behavior, and while it has semi-predictable results on most compilers, it's incredibly fragile; any function call at all, implicit or explicit, could stomp on the value that pointer is referencing.

Comment: [In a newer version of GCC it would](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-error-when-using-gcc-compile-option-werror#comment130946668_38840601) be [`-Wno-return-local-addr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-return-local-addr) instead of `-Wno-return-stack-address`

Comment: What is the latest version of GCC to support `-Wno-return-stack-address`? (I can't find it anywhere in the documentation for the current version). That would put version constraints on what the OP was using. Search engines are very unwilling to reveal this information. Is there a more efficient technique when it comes to navigating the GCC documentation, incl. older versions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: No idea. The OP told me what the warning switch was, I told them to add `no-` to the name to disable it.

Comment: OK, I found [a more efficient search method](https://github.com/barro/compiler-warnings#gcc-warning-flags).

Comment: A search should be *without* the three letters "-no" (or use just the last part). `-Wreturn-local-addr` was [apparently introduced with GCC 4.8](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/gcc/warnings-gcc-4.8.txt) ([was released](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) 2015-06-23). It wasn't in [GCC 4.7](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/gcc/warnings-gcc-4.7.txt).

Comment: The OP has probably ***not*** used GCC, but some other compiler (with *some* common option names). `-Wreturn-stack-address` seems to have been [introduced in Clang 3.3](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/clang/warnings-clang-3.3.txt) and is in the latest version (not listed for [3.2](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/clang/warnings-clang-3.2.txt)). Clang 3.3 was released before 2015, [some time in 2012 - 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang#Status_history).

Comment: No wonder it was so difficult to find!!!

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I'm pretty sure I've seen some weirdo systems that aliased `gcc` to `clang`, so I wouldn't be surprised if the OP legit thought they were using `gcc` when they were not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [gcc documentation about `-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), you can "negate `-Werror` for specific warnings" with `-Wno-error=`. In our case, we can ignore `-Wreturn-stack-address` `-Wno-error=return-stack-address` as follows:

```
gcc -Werror -Wno-error=return-stack-address test.c -o test
```

As already stated another answer here, you can disable most warnings by appending `no-` to the warning name. In the documentation linked above:

> Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning `-Wno-` to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`."

I recognize that the example given is this question is just an example. Places where I've needed this are from compiling external libraries that I cannot edit, due to licensing or other reasons. Often, I can put in a ticket to remove the warning, but in the meantime, I assess the risk and choose to silence the warning until an update comes.