# LibHaru Qt 5 cannot find usr/local/lib. File format not recognized

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-14.04, libharu

I installed libraries from *libharu.org* accordingly to the instructions on the page (without any errors). Then I tried to run an example in Qt 5. After adding paths to installed directories

```
INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include
LIBS +=/usr/local/lib -libhpdf
```

Qt 5 seemed to find them (headers underline disappeared).
However, during debug, it shows errors:

```
cannot find /usr/local/lib: File format not recognized
cannot find -libhpdf
```

with

```
LIBS += -L/usr/...
```

instead gives errors with every libharu header, *undefined reference to HPDF_xxx*.

Comment: I am not sure; but what about `INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include` and 
`LIBS +=-L/usr/local/lib -lhpdf` note that I used `-lhpdf` instead of `-libhpdf` and ensure that file `hpdf.a` exists in the mentioned path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include
LIBS +=-L/usr/local/lib -lhpdf
```

Note that I used `-lhpdf` instead of `-libhpdf` and ensure that file `libhpdf.a` exists in the mentioned path.

See this answer: *[How can I include a needed C library using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016851/992406)*

Comment: This doesn't explain [the *why*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641768/adding-c-external-library-in-visual-studio-code#comment99890420_56641768).