# Adding a C external library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

How can I add an external C library in Visual Studio Code?

I read *[How can I include a needed C library using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc)* and tried:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "build",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-L \\C:\\MinGW\\lib",
            "-l libws2_32.a"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ]
    }
]
```

But I got

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l libws2_32.a 
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And I installed GCC in folder *C:\MinGW*.

Comment: Try `-lws2_32`.

Comment: thanks!! btw can you explain how it work?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Libraries "-l*library* [...] Static libraries are archives of object files, and have file names like lib*library*.a." I.e. `-lws2_32` looks for a file called `libws2_32.a`.

Comment: What is that format? [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)? Where did you put it? In file *settings.json*?