# How do you compile a C file that includes GLUT?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors, glut

I am currently using Visual Studio Code to create a game using [GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit) for graphics, as included by `#include "GL/glut.h"`. However, when I compile it,

```
gcc main.c -o test
```

I am faced with

```
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12\
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0xa77): undefined reference to `glBegin@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0xa90): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0xb49): undefined reference to `glVertex2d@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0xb60): undefined reference to `glVertex2d@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `glEnd@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x54a8): undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x54bf): undefined reference to `glBlendFunc@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x55dc): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x55eb): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x55f3): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5609): undefined reference to `glScalef@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5634): undefined reference to `gluPerspective@32'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5643): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x564b): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x568a): undefined reference to `gluLookAt@72'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x57d1): undefined reference to `glEnableClientState@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x57e0): undefined reference to `glEnableClientState@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5807): undefined reference to `glVertexPointer@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x582e): undefined reference to `glTexCoordPointer@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x584e): undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5875): undefined reference to `glVertexPointer@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x589c): undefined reference to `glTexCoordPointer@16'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x58bc): undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x58cb): undefined reference to `glDisable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x58da): undefined reference to `glBegin@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x58f3): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x590c): undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5927): undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5940): undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x595b): undefined reference to `glVertex3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5974): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x597c): undefined reference to `glEnd@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5988): undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5990): undefined reference to `_imp__glutPostRedisplay@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5997): undefined reference to `_imp__glutSwapBuffers@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x599e): undefined reference to `glFlush@0'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x59f6): undefined reference to `_imp__glutSetCursor@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5a53): undefined reference to `_imp__glutSetCursor@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5b8c): undefined reference to `_imp__glutWarpPointer@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5bef): undefined reference to `_imp__glutGet@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5c05): undefined reference to `_imp__glutGet@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5ccd): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5ce6): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowSize@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5cff): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowPosition@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d1f): undefined reference to `_imp__glutKeyboardFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d30): undefined reference to `_imp__glutKeyboardUpFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d41): undefined reference to `_imp__glutDisplayFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d52): undefined reference to `_imp__glutReshapeFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d63): undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d78): undefined reference to `glAlphaFunc@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d87): undefined reference to `_imp__glutSetCursor@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5d98): undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5db1): undefined reference to `_imp__glutPassiveMotionFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5dc2): undefined reference to `_imp__glutMotionFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5dd3): undefined reference to `_imp__glutMouseFunc@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5dec): undefined reference to `glPixelStorei@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5e03): undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5e1b): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5e6f): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5e90): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5eb1): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5ed2): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5ef3): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5f12): undefined reference to `glTexEnvi@12'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5f21): undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgUQvpv.o:main.c:(.text+0x5f29): undefined reference to `_imp__glutMainLoop@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After googling around for solutions, I have also tried (combinations of *-lglut*, *-lGLU* and *-lGL*)

```
gcc main.c -o test -lglut
```

Which returns

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGL
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGLU
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut
```

I have opened the file in Xcode on my Mac, however, and while the terminal command of GCC gets faced with a similar Clang error, Xcode's built-in 'build' successfully creates the application.

Additionally, my code used quite a lot of [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and C++ didn't work for that, so I'd really like to get this working for C. Visual Studio 2019 didn't like building my solution either, as it didn't like the VLAs.

How can I get GCC to compile this file when it includes GLUT?

How do you compile a C file that includes GLUT?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [-L<Directory name>](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-L) to tell the compiler where to find the library you want to link ([GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit), [GLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library) and [GL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)), because they cannot be found in standard list of directories.

Refer to the official GCC document: *[Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)*

> -llibrary
> -l library Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
> compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your
> linker documentation for exact details. The general description below
> applies to the GNU linker.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library.
> The directories searched include several standard system directories
> **plus any that you specify with -L**.

The existing question and answers would provide the clear example:
*[How can I include a needed C library using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc)*