# What does "gcc -lm -o [executable_name] [file_name].c" mean?

Tags: c, command-line

Specifically, what does the "-lm" mean, and is it required to include that? Is there a "dictionary" online that will explain all of these command abbreviations like "-lm"?

Comment: `-lstuff` means 'link the executable with a library called "stuff"'.

Comment: This is called documentation or manual. Like in RTFM.

Comment: @Olaf My professor required that all students use "gcc -lm -o" to compile our C programs. I don't really know what the "-lm" means, though.

Comment: And instead of reading the docs, want it spoon-fed? That's hardly what your prof wants you to do.

Comment: What documents? I have literally zero idea of what documents you are referring to.

Comment: Those are called _flags_. Google 'GCC compiler flags' and you'll [get your 'dictionary'](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

Comment: @Olaf I guess you were referring to the documentation that Attie linked. The problem is that I didn't know what to Google. If I typed into Google, "What does 'gcc -lm -o' mean?", I don't get any tangible results. Feel free to try it yourself.

All I received was an assignment PDF from my professor. The first assignment only required students to compile with "gcc -o". Now, this assignment requires students to compile with "gcc -lm -o", and so I had no idea where the "-lm" came from.

Comment: You are using `gcc`, right? So it is pretty obvious that you need `gcc` documentation.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you so much. I didn't know they were called "flags". That's what I called them "abbreviations" in my original question. It really helps to know the terminology.

Comment: @FridaySky FYI, if you Google 'Porsche - Carrera', you'll get search results having 'Porsche' that does not have 'Carrera' in it. For Google, `-` is a special character which excludes stuff. So, if you search 'GCC -lm', you'll get search results having GCC without 'lm'. To avoid this, Google either `GCC lm` or `GCC "-lm"`.

Comment: Google "gcc documentation" would be the obvious. And these **options** (they are not flags!) are standard for command line arguments. That is basic computer knowledge. If in doubt, you should ask your prof to add this information. Just don't eat everything he tells you without asking if something is unclear.

Comment: @Olaf It's not entirely obvious for me since I wouldn't use the word "documentation". I probably would type in "gcc compiler" and "gcc commands" and "command prompt commands".

Comment: Apparently you did not even try these!

Comment: @Olaf I can definitely tell you about data structures like linked lists, stacks, and queues, but I've never been exposed to the nitty-gritty like gcc documentation, options/flags, etc.

I didn't try them because "what does gcc -lm -o mean" didn't work for me.

Comment: The canonical may be *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)* (18 answers. 314 upvotes. 2009.)

Comment: Which is a duplicate of *[GCC -lm -lz -lrt options - what are they about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663097/gcc-lm-lz-lrt-options-what-are-they-about)* (2011).

Comment: @PeterMortensen why are you bringing this up now? As someone said above: "For Google, - is a special character which excludes stuff. So, if you search 'GCC -lm', you'll get search results having GCC without 'lm'. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is linking against the `m` library... Which is used for math functions.

The [`-l<library name>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l) parameter to `gcc` means '*link with this library*'.

The `m` is the library to link with (e.g: `libm.so` or `libm.a`).

See the [GCC man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) (run `man gcc`), and functions like [`sin()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sin), `sqrt()`, `pow()`, etc.

Note that in these man pages, it states:

> Link with -lm.

Comment: Don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: This helped so much. Thank you for the link. I'll mark Best Answer asap.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully your professor could have answered that as well - don't be afraid to ask for help, how else will you learn?

Comment: @Attie google it? :)

Comment: @ChrisTurner In general, yes I agree. But for something so teeny-wee, Googling is tricky to do correctly, especially for beginners... you think `what does gcc -lm mean` might work? Not likely... it'll exclude `lm` from the search terms (yay). It's a big world, and we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: @Attie works just fine if you put quotes around the -lm and gives several useful results *shrugs*

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yeah, I know... not my point. How did you *know* to quote it? Magic?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I actually typed in exactly what Attie said: "what does gcc -lm -o mean". When that didn't work on Google, I went to Bing. When that didn't work, I was going to send my TA an email but he specified that he only responds on Fridays. So, then I looked it up on Stack Overflow because maybe Google missed those results. I didn't find anything either, so I asked a question.

Until you mentioned it, Chris, I didn't know putting quotes around a word was a good trick to Googling effectively.

Answer (score 2):

[-l](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l) stands for library and here by using *-lm*, you are telling GCC to use the math library. If your program is using functions like *pow*, *sqrt*, *floor* or others from the math library, you need to tell the compiler to link it with the math library and that’s what it’s doing.

Comment: Quick question (and it's fine if you don't want to answer it): But why won't #include <math.h> do the trick anyway? Or would I need to "gcc -lm" in conjunction with #include <math.h>? Sorry, I used to compile my programs on CodeBlocks for my Intro to C course, so compiling through the command line is kind of weird for me.

Comment: There are two parts to using a library - the function 'prototypes' (aka API), and the actual executable implementation. You need to link with both. There are also multiple steps to 'compiling' an application - 'compiling', and 'linking'. Worth reading up on.