# A linking error related to 'gcc' and '-lm'

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, linker, ld, math.h

Well, I think my problem is a little bit interesting and I want to understand what's happening on my Ubuntu box.

I compiled and linked the following useless piece of code with `gcc -lm -o useless useless.c`:

```
/* File useless.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int sample = (int)(0.75 * 32768.0 * sin(2 * 3.14 * 440 * ((float) 1/44100)));
    return(0);
}
```

So far so good. But when I change to this:

```
/* File useless.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int freq = 440;
    int sample = (int)(0.75 * 32768.0 * sin(2 * 3.14 * freq * ((float) 1/44100)));
    return(0);
}
```

And I try to compile using the same command line, and `gcc` responds:

```
/tmp/cctM0k56.o: In function `main':
ao_example3.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And it stops. What is happening? Why can't I compile that way?

I also tried a `sudo ldconfig -v` without success.

Comment: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.  The parentheses on the `return` statement are unnecessary; you can just write `return 0;`.

Comment: For that matter, in C99 or later you can just omit the `return 0;`.

Comment: Related: *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)* (18 answers. 314 upvotes. 2009.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two different things going on here.

For the first example, the compiler doesn't generate a call to `sin`.  It sees that the argument is a constant expression, so it replaces the `sin(...)` call with the result of the expression, and the math library isn't needed.  It will work just as well without the `-lm`.  (But you shouldn't count on that; it's not always obvious when the compiler will perform this kind of optimization and when it won't.)

(If you compile with

```
gcc -S useless.c
```

and take a look at `useless.s`, the generated assembly language listing, you can see that there's no call to `sin`.)

For the second example, you do need the `-lm` option -- but it needs to be at the end of the command line, or at least after the file (`useless.c`) that needs it:

```
gcc -o useless useless.c -lm
```

or

```
gcc useless.c -lm -o useless
```

The linker processes files in order, keeping track of unresolved symbols for each one (`sin`, referred to by `useless.o`), and then resolving them as it sees their definitions.  If you put the `-lm` first, there are no unresolved symbols when it processes the math library; by the time it sees the call to `sin` in `useless.o`, it's too late.

Comment: I was about to post the same but could not understand why the first succeeded (`sin()` is also used).

Comment: I've rearranged the answer (it still has the same information).