# What is the meaning of -lm in GCC?

Tags: gcc

When I compile some C code with `gcc`, it needs adding `-lm`.
For example, when I want to use `fmax` in my program, I must use the following command:

```
gcc myprogram.c -lm
```

What happens to my program by adding `-lm`? What does `-lm` mean?

Comment: The canonical may be *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)* (18 answers. 314 upvotes. 2009.)

Comment: Possible duplicate (2011): *[GCC -lm -lz -lrt options - what are they about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663097/gcc-lm-lz-lrt-options-what-are-they-about)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's say you have the *main.c* file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float my_foo(float a, float b)
{
    return fmax(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", my_foo(4.5, 3.1));
    return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile it without the `-lm` flag, you will receive am *undefined reference* error:

```
main.o: In function `my_foo':
main.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `fmax'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is because the linker does not know any implementation of the `fmax` function. You have to provide it.

In [gcc man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), you can find the following description of the `-llibrary` flag:

> **Search the library named library when linking.** (The second alternative       with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.

> **The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.**

> The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.

> Normally the files found this way are library files---archive files whose members are object files. The linker handles an archive file by scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. **The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with lib and .a and searches several directories.**

It looks that I have the *libm.a* file stored at */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a*:

```
$ find /usr/lib -iname libm.a

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
```

You can check that *libm.a* contains the definition of `fmax`:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a --defined-only | grep fmax

[...]
s_fmax.o:
0000000000000000 W fmax
[...]
```

In case the command above will result in an error with following result:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a

nm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a: file format not recognized
```

It may be caused by the fact that *your* distribution provides *libm.a* as a linker script.

```
$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a: ASCII text
```

#### File */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a*

```
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.a )
```

The script basically informs the linker to try to link `libm-2.31.a` and `libmvec.a`. See the GROUP description in *[Using LD, the GNU linker](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html)*.

So you should be able to verify that the `fmax` implementation is provided in `libm-2.31.a` with:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.a --defined-only 2> /dev/null | grep -w fmax

0000000000000000 W fmax
```

Comment: For some reason I get `file format not recognized` for `nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a`.

Comment: @Adobe Thank you for mentioning that. I was able to "reproduce" your issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and described short explanation in my answer.

Comment: Does gcc automatically include this library nowadays? I can compile and run this code without the -lm option.

Comment: @aganm Did you by any chance compiled the code with `g++` instead of `gcc`? If yes, the code was compiled as `C++` not `C` and `C++` standard library requires `libm` by default. You can find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12453417/3188346. If no, could you please share the command you used for compilation? I just tried this on Ubuntu 21.04 and `-lm` was necessary to link the executable.

Comment: @luantkow Nevermind, I did something wrong. You are correct.

Comment: Don't omit "-lm" even when using C++. If you call a function of libm, you must link to libm and don't rely on implicit dependencies. Or your command may fail with different linux distributions.

Answer (score 62):

TLDNR: math.h is not a part of the standard C library, so you have to link to it!

-l*library* searches the library *library* while linking. The *m* stands for *libm*, the library that contains <math.h>. For more information, see [these](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC13) [couple](https://hpc.llnl.gov/software/mathematical-software/libm#:%7E:text=LIBM%20is%20the%20standard%20C,optimized%20implementations%20of%20LIBM%20functions.) [links](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libm.html).

@[luantkow's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44176189/11650766) answer is really good but long! Here's a short version if you don't want to read! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @kk is the information in the answer wrong? Can you tell me why?

Comment: "math.h is not a part of the standard C library" Sure it is. But it may not be part of the specific default lib used by a certain gcc port.

Comment: @Lundin No, it is not. C++ requires math.h, C does not. The fact is only stdxxx.h are considered standard library, -lc flag

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников No, that is wrong and I have no idea how you came up with that delusion. A _freestanding_ implementation in C may pick a vert limited subset of standard headers (C17 4 §6), whereas a conforming hosted implementation must implement all of the mandatory headers in chapter 7 which is most of them. The std prefix doesn't have any significant meaning at all; in fact some like stdatomic.h are optional.