# undefined reference to 'log','exp','log10' opencv4.5.4

Tags: android, c++, opencv, shared-libraries

Iam build OpenCV 4.5.4 from source for Android and ABI x64_86, with NDK r21e.
Build was success without errors.
Then I create a Shared Object project in Visual Studio 2022,
where are a simple function to summ 2 Mat objects.
In project properies(Release x64) I put refs to include folder "...native\jni\include",
and link static(*.a) compiled libs "native\staticlibs\x86_64", "native\3rdparty\libs\x86_64"
Linked libs:

```
opencv_core
ippiw
ittnotify
ippicv
zlib
```

When I trying to build(Release x64), I have some link errors:

```
1> undefined reference to 'log'
1> undefined reference to 'log10'
1> undefined reference to 'exp'
1> undefined reference to 'log'
1> undefined reference to 'exp'
1> undefined reference to 'exp'
1> undefined reference to 'logf'
1> undefined reference to 'logf'
1>clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with -lm flag at
Linker/Additional Options.
And for me is still a riddle what that flag(-lm) means?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175151/what-is-the-meaning-of-lm-in-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175151/what-is-the-meaning-of-lm-in-gcc)