# Does gnu ld link in whole object files or only the needed functions?

Tags: static-libraries, ld, avr-gcc

We have a library and an executable, that is to be *statically* linked to the lib. We want to minimize the program space of the final executable.

According to avr-libc's documentation:

> [the linker links in THE ENTIRE OBJECT MODULE in which the function is located](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/library.html)

On the other hand, my colleagues  are unanimous on the point that at some pass, the linker throws away any unused functions.

So who is correct or am I misunderstanding something? Is the answer consistent throughout gcc or are we talking only the avr port here?

Comment: the linker cannot know if a function will be called, for instance by a function pointer.

Comment: I guess if a function name is mentioned in the sources, the function is considered "used", so must be linked in.

Comment: usually it's compiler task, as Nikos C. highlights

Comment: A "how to do it version": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't perform dead code stripping unless you tell it to. In order to do that, you need to compile everything with:

```
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
```

in order to mark all data and functions. And when linking with GCC you need to pass:

```
-Wl,--gc-sections
```

in order to garbage-collect all unused sections.

Comment: So both of my sources were correct and I had not understood everything correct. Just as expected. Thank you for the prompt answer!