# File Global Define

Tags: c, header, c-preprocessor

I am making a small, library, and I want to give the user the option to disable the parts they do not require.

lib.h

```
#ifndef ONLY_BASICS
    void complexFunction(void);
#endif
```

lib.c

```
#ifndef ONLY_BASICS
    void complexFunction(void) {
        printf("damn, this is complex alright!\n");
    }
#endif
```

main.c

```
#define ONLY_BASICS
#include "lib.h"
```

I have seen this being done in other libraries, what am I missing?

Comment: "what am I missing?" A question related to a problem you're having?

Comment: Yes, I am still able to call the function even will the ONLY_BASICS set.

Comment: The problem is that `ONLY_BASICS` is only defined in `main.c`. `lib.c` will, therefore, define `complexFunction`. I don't think you can achieve what you're attempting with the `define` mechanism and still keep `lib.h` generic. However, when you compile, it should at least warn you that you're trying to call `complexFunction` without a function prototype. What other library have you seen use this technique?

Comment: OK, now I understand the problem. But is there a solution?

Comment: Can you put `#define ONLY_BASICS` in `lib.h`? Then it would work as long as other parts of the code don't need the complex items in `lib.c`. If `lib.c` is serving some modules that need `complexFunction` and some that don't, then what you're attempting to do is not achievable as a compile-time option. Either `complexFunction` exists in your build, or it doesn't it can't be both.

Comment: Yes, but you see. Different projects may, or may not need the define. I don't want the user to have to modify the internals of the library each time they want to change the settings.

Comment: Unless I put the code in the header file.

Comment: Jimmay, Your problem is really a two part problem. One is visibility, as @mbratch has explained. The tags you have used on this post suggest the answer to this problem - use a precompiler define. The second problem is that it is bad form to edit a library file within a project. So you will not be (should not be) surrounding code (lib.c/.h) with the exclusion ONLY_BASICS.

Comment: It sounds like you need to versions of the library: `lib_simple` and `lib_complex` if you want to physically remove the ability to call `complexFunction` when only the simple case is desired. As I mentioned before, using your current scheme, you should at least be able to generate a compiler message if the function isn't defined (prototyped) in the `ONLY_BASICS` case. But you can't prevent it from being built into the lib if you need it sometimes and it will exist as a public symbol.

Comment: If by "I want to give the user the option to disable the parts they do not require" you mean you want them to be able to disable the parts *while they're compiling the library*, then you can just set the relevant `#define` using a compiler option, then they don't have to mess with the actual files. With gcc, for instance, you'd include `-DONLY_BASICS` as an option when compiling. If you want them to be able to do it after the library has already compiled, then the other answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make users control the build using the prepossessing macros from the compiler without editing the code. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) use the switch `-D` followed by the macro name. On [Microsoft compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) use the `/D` option.

For example using GCC, I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

#ifdef SAYHI
    #ifdef CAPITAL
    printf("HI\n");
    #else
    printf("hi\n");
    #endif
#elif SAYHELLO
    #ifdef CAPITAL
    printf("HELLO\n");
    #else
    printf("hello\n");
    #endif
#else
    #ifdef CAPITAL
    printf("SAY SOMETHING\n");
    #else
    printf("say something\n");
    #endif
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

The user can enable and disable what he want via `-DMACRO` without editing the code, example:

```
$ gcc main.c
$ a.exe
say something
$ 
$ gcc main.c -DCAPITAL
$ a.exe
SAY SOMETHING
$ 
$ gcc main.c -DSAYHI -DCAPITAL
$ a.exe
HI
$ 
$ gcc main.c -DSAYHELLO
$ a.exe
hello
$
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're misunderstanding what a library is and what it's used for.  Most (all?) linkers already do what you're trying by not including unreferenced symbols from libraries - it's why with gcc, for instance, you need to put the libraries at the *end* of the command line after the list of source files that contain references to library functions.

What you're doing seems to be confusing this behaviour with compile-time options for the library itself.  In that case, you can use the `#ifndef` blocks as you have in `lib.h` and `lib.c`, but you shouldn't need to do anything in `main.c` - the library will already have been built without `complexFunction`.  You may want to have your library build process generate a header that describes which functionality is available.

Comment: Are you sure? [Does gnu ld link in whole object files or only the needed functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13525970/1145760)

Comment: That's why libraries are often compiled with `-ffunction-sections` or with a single function per translation unit.