# C fabs returning integer

Tags: c, math.h

I have a strange problem with fabs function in C code. I have two double values and I want to find the absolute value of their difference using code like this:

```
a = 87.967498;
b = 218.025015;
if (fabs(a-b)<2.0)
...code to execute
```

The value of `fabs(a-b)` is an int and is equal to 1. I don't know whats the problem here and I can't find anything on the net. Any help would be great!!

Comment: Also, you might have to link the math.h manually. 

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

Comment: A `fabs` macro maybe? Do a `grep -w fabs *.c *.h` to check

Comment: hi @Przemysław, have you figure out the problem ? I remember I had the same problem. it went away after I clean everything and made a fresh build of my project.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include `<math.h>`. Add the following line to your other includes:

```
#include <math.h>
```

In order to find such errors easier I recommend you to use verbose compiler warnings (`gcc -Wall -Wextra ...` if you use gcc).

Comment: This is only a part of the code - math.h is included and works fine, because the program uses a lot of other math.h methods.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that `fabs` could return an `int` is either:

- Your program uses a declaration of `fabs` other than the version declared in `math.h`.
- Your program failed to include `math.h` and so does not declare `fabs` at all. In which case parameters and return values default to `int`. Which is of course an error because the actual implementation of `fabs` does not match and so the value returned is nonsense.

Comment: The code I posted is a part of a large program using a lot of `math.h' methods and they work fine, because the whole program works generally fine. Of course except this small piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 87.967498;
    float b = 218.025015;
    float diff = a-b;

    printf("diff=%f\nfabs(diff)=%f\n",diff,fabs(diff));
    if (fabs(diff)<2.0) {
        printf("OK\n");
    } else {
        printf("FAIL\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
diego@malti:~/tmp$ clang test-math.c -o test-math -lm
diego@malti:~/tmp$ ./test-math 
diff=-130.057510
fabs(diff)=130.057510
FAIL
```

See? The application is OK, the diff (218-87=130), which is not smaller then 2.

See also then when I am compile, I also link `-lm` to get the mathematical library. The same syntax applies for gcc, I just love using clang :)

Comment: I compiled that code and got the same output (well, except user@machine stuff...)  However, when I run it under gdb I get this:
`    (gdb) p fabs(diff)
    $1 = 1
    (gdb) p diff
    $2 = -130.05751`