# <stdio.h> vs <math.h> - Why do you have to link one and not the other?

Tags: c

I'm confused why you have to type -lm to properly link math to your code, but don't have to do the same for stdio. I've only just started using C, so I apologize if this is a stupid quesiton or I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c?rq=1

Comment: `*.h` files are header files, header files are **not** linked, headers are **`include`ed**!

Answer (score 7):

In short, because of historical reasons,

The functions in `stdio.h` are in `libc`, while the functions in `math.h` are in `libm`. `libc` is linked by default but `libm` isn't.

Comment: s/was/is/, to be correct.

Comment: And the historical reasons were, while virtually everybody needed the code in `libc`, the code in `libm` was required by only a few applications.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different things:

- header files (`stdio.h` and `math.h`) - they contain only function prototypes and some definitions and data; they are **`#include`d** in your **source code**
- libraries (`libm.so`) - they contain **binary** code which will be **linked** back into your application (**binary code**). Also, for a library named `libname.so` the linker flag is `-lname` - for `libm.so` the flag is `-lm`.

Take also in consideration that there are `libc.so` and `libstdc.so` which are always linked into your application. Code for functions in `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` and several others is found on those libraries - thus, it is always included.

PS: I'm assuming Linux/UNIX here, thus the names are very specific. On Windows things are similar but with other names (DLLs instead of `.so` files, etc.)

Comment: The names `libm.so`, `libc.so`, etc., are very system-specific. But then so is the requirement to use `-lm` to link the math library.

Comment: Thanks, mentioned that in a PS.