# Math function compiler linking error

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, virtual-machine, math.h

The following code compiles on other systems, but not on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit guest in Virtualbox 4.3.10 on a Windows 7 64bit host.

### hello.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    double x;
        x = testfunction();
    printf("%f \n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

### hello2.c

```
#include "header.h"

double testfunction ()
{
int i = 1;
double j = 0;
for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    j += sin(i/M_PI);
return j;
}
```

### header.h

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double testfunction();
```

When I attempt to compile using

> gcc -lm -o hello hello.c hello2.c

I receive the error

> /tmp/ccirukEU.o: In function `testfunction':
>   hello2.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to`sin'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The error remains even if I include math.h directly in hello2.c. Calculating sin(2/M_Pi) rather than sin(i/M_Pi) removes the error, possibly because gcc then works out the sine itself rather than using the math library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-lm` in the end, as in:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c hello2.c -lm
```

This ensures that the linker can realize that there are dependencies missing. Using `-lm` in the beginning is known to raise problems, because by the time the linker looks at the math library, it hasn't looked at your code yet, so there are no dependencies unresolved.