# GNUjump not building on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, gnu, archlinux

I'm trying to build GNUjump on Arch Linux (release 1 Oct. 2014), but i'm getting a strange error, and i don't know what to do.

./configure shows me no error. So, i launch make, and this appears:

```
/usr/bin/ld: SDL_rotozoom.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sincos@@GLIBC_2.1'
/usr/lib/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The same Makefile, on a Debian-based PC, works.
Surely, i'm missing something, but i don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `-lm` in the compiler/linker command line to link against the standard math library `math.h`.
See this: [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Comment: Thanks. But why the same makefile works in a Debian environment? I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Hard to say, @AlbyV0D. It might depend on lots of things, like default setting, compiler and back-end used, the makefile itself and so on. Have you managed to compile it?

Comment: I solved using another distro (always Arch-based), and working inside one of the Makefiles. Thanks for your help.