# Does compiler provide these functions: printf, scanf?

Tags: c

I'm studying C language nowadays. In this book, it is said that the "compiler provides these library functions: 'printf','scanf'…".

I can't understand. Those functions are defined in the header file `<stdio.h>` aren't they?

Why does this book explain those functions are provided by the compiler?

Comment: which book is that? Good question btw.

Comment: @cacho It is a programming book written by Korean author. C Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf`, `scanf`, and the other standard library functions are provided as part of the *implementation*.

A C implementation is made up of several components. The compiler is just one of them. The library is another; it consists of *headers* (commonly provided as source files like `stdio.h`) and some form of *object code* files containing the code that actually implements the library functions.

The header `stdio.h` only *declares* these functions; it doesn't *define* them. The declaration of `printf` is something like:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

The *definition* of `printf` is the code that actually does the job of parsing the format string, accessing the arguments, and sending the formatted output to `stdout`. That's typically (but not necessarily) written in C and provided as some kind of linkable object code.

For some C implementations, the compiler and the library are provided by the same organization. For others, they might be provided separately (for example MinGW combines the gcc compiler with Microsoft's library).

Comment: Then, "the compiler provides library functions" is wrong statement?

Comment: Are they separated thing, right? 

I mean, 'C library functions' ,  'compiler'.

Comment: A complete implementation for C provides a compiler and the runtime support needed.  On many Unix systems, the C runtime library is somewhat separate from the compilers, but the compiler must know how to create programs (otherwise it isn't much use) and must know which library it is going to use.  But the compiler is very definitely a wholly separate program from either the programs you create with it or from the 'default C library' (which isn't even a program — it is just a library).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The compiler doesn't necessarily have to know which library the program will use; that's up to the linker.

Comment: And then you get into questions of 'what is the compiler' — yes, you're right, and yes (IMO, of course) I'm also right, but we're using different definitions of the term 'compiler' which is why we're both right for our different definitions.

Answer (score 5):

The functions are provided by the *standard library*, which is a collection of precompiled code that is typically written by the compiler authors (but it is indeed not a part of the compiler itself).

Note, though, that the functions are only *declared* in the header files. The *definition* resides in source files that have already been compiled.

Comment: Um... sorry I don't understand.
If the functions are declared in the header files, why is it needed to provide those functions from standard library again?

Comment: @nujabes: the header files only contain the *prototypes*, which is all that is needed your file to compile; the actual implementation is usually provided already compiled in some static or dynamic library. This avoids the need to recompile the whole standard library each time you build your program.

Comment: @nujabes: Because the header file does not contain the code that implements the functions.  The implementation object files are in the standard library; the header simply declares the functions that are defined for you to use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh Thank you , that makes sense!

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thank you! then "Compiler provides library functions" statement is wrong, right? 

Summary: 
Library function is just library function.
The compiler just translate those function.

Is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

By saying, "Compiler provides these library functions , 'printf','scanf'..", the author of the book is being sloppy.

A standard conforming C implementation provides declarations of those functions in header files and implementations of those functions in some short of library. A compiler is just one aspect of a C programming environment.

Comment: Thank you !
You said "some short of library" , is it standard library ?

Comment: @nujabes, different programming environments provide different ways of supporting the standard library. I didn't want to be very specific.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not provide those functions. The goal of the compiler is to translate your high-level language code into another form, in particular an executable binary.

The standard C library contains the functions in stdio.h and stdlib.h.

The compiler **[links](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)** the standard library with your code so that your code can call those functions.

For almost all libraries, you have to tell the compiler what libraries you want to link. It so happens that for some compilers, the library (libc) for stdio.h and stlib.h is [automatically linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c) without you needing to specify them.

Comment: The default C library normally supplies all the C functions from the Standard C library except (perhaps — it depends on the platform) the maths functions from `<math.h>`.  (I've never needed to use `<tgmath.h>`; I'm not sure whether they go with the the maths functions or with the other functions.)  When the maths library is separate, it is normally loaded with `-lm`, and the name is `libm.a` or something similar – but library names and extensions vary by platform.  Mac OS X has the maths functions in the main library. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  I don't much like terminology that talks about 'the stdio and stdlib libraries'.  There are headers `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`, but there's only one library (or two libraries) — the C library (and perhaps the maths library).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks. I changed the wording of "the stdio and stdlib libraries" to be "the library (libc) for stdio.h and stlib.h".

Answer (score 1):

Those functions provided by standard library and GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the standard C library. 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html