# compilation of Makefile gives 'ld returned, DSO missing' errors

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am new to the Unix system; have been trying to install and compile a code using a `Makefile`, but I get the following error:

```
gcc -o ../zmass zmass.o useful.o open.o -O3 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
/usr/bin/ld: zmass.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../zmass] Error 1
```

Could anybody help me with this? I have already installed `gtk+-2.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `-lm` after `` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` `` in your `Makefile`

Comment: thanks! that solved the problem. Could you please explain a bit about the significance of introducing -lm?

Comment: @Ana See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033940/1517864) to the the question [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1033898/1517864)