# C libm.a not needed to be linked when compiling

Tags: c, gcc

I was trying to compile a source file that includes `<math.h>`. 
However I succeeded in creating an executable, no error without linking to `libm.a`.

The command I typed was `gcc -Wall filename.c -o executablename`

I was told to link to the external libraries (i.e/ libraries other than libc.a)

What's going on?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = sqrt(2.0);
    printf ("The sqrt of 2 is: %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which platform?  That's normal on Mac OS X, for example.  Also, how did you use the functions from `<math.h>`?  If the values could be computed by the compiler, then they probably were and the functions needn't be called in the executable, so the linking wouldn't notice that you didn't link with the maths library.

Comment: Add a `-v` to your command line and you'll immediately see what's going on.

Comment: Is that a copy-paste of the exact code you're using? Because `sqrt()` only takes one argument, not two.

Comment: gcc fixed this bug a while ago

Comment: @M.M Which bug? Not having to `-lm`? Or `sqrt()` not taking two arguments ;-)

Comment: sorry I added 3.0 for some reason

Comment: I don't get an error either when I am on windows. On Ubuntu I do get an error.

Answer (score 6):

The math functions you call are implemented by compiler built-in functions. Try the following if you want to see an error message:

```
gcc -fno-builtin -Wall filename.c -o executablename
```

For example, on my platform (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS), I get this error message:

```
$ cat x.c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = sqrt(2.0);
    printf ("The sqrt of 2 is: %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -fno-builtin x.c
/tmp/ccpjG2Pb.o: In function `main':
x.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Nope even with the -fno-builtin and -Wall flags it still compiles without an error

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest possible program that still demonstrates your question. Please copy-paste that program into your question. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the above error with the option `-fno-builtin`. Without it, the program compiles even if I haven't specified the `-lm` option to gcc.

Comment: @jdhao - That is precisely the same behavior I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers, like the current `clang` on OS X (which masquerades as `gcc`) do not need to be told to link your executable with the math library.

The `clang` on OS X will link your executable with `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` (and only this for a simple program).  This library in turn uses the library `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib` which is the math library.

Comment: What if I'm using gcc on cygwin

Comment: @hemel Check what libraries are linked against your compiled executable. On an ordinary Unix system, this would be done with `ldd a.out`. You might spot `libm` in there.  It's never _wrong_ to link with `-lm` when you use math functions... and since this has to do with linking rather than compiling, I don't think `-Wall` would do very much in terms of reporting (since it mainly deals with code issues, not linking issues).

Answer (score 0):

The functions in `<math.h>` (or the preferable `<tgmath.h>`) are part of the C library just as many other functions. It is platform dependent if all the functions in the C library are actually linked in one single library or separately in multiple chunks.

In ancient times the size of the libraries was a problem for link time, the larger a library was, the longer it took to link executables that had many unresolved symbols. These times are long gone, but the separation on some platforms into `libc.a` and `libm.a` prevails.

If your platform doesn't need `-lm` for linking it should have a dummy (empty) version of `libm.a` just that there is no error when you have that on your link command line. This is for example the case for the [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/) C library that is at the base of Alpine Linux.

Comment: Another historical reason for the separate maths library was that some machines didn't have hardware floating point and so needed a software emulation library, while others did have hardware floating point and didn't need the emulation.  This was easier to manage if the two libraries were separate.

Comment: Does that mean that libc.a may support functions of libm.a?

Comment: @hemel The `libc` (or whatever the system chooses to call it) can contain everything, including math, cryptographic, networking and graphics rendering routines if it makes sense on a particular platform.

Comment: @hemel, I suppose you mean if it can contain functions from `<math.h>`? Yes. How the linking is done is not part of the C standard.