# C power function and scanf

Tags: c, math, input, printf, scanf

So basically, I need to get an input and square it. some reason the `pow()` function isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (){

  int in, ans;
  scans("%d", &in);
  ans = pow(in, 2);
  printf("answer is: %d", ans);
  return 0;

}
```

The error is :

> `undefined pow or something like that`

Comment: answer is , 'show exact error message' , or something like that

Comment: Assuming a linker error?  Hard to say when we don't have an exact error message.  Could always do `in * in` to square it too.

Comment: I strongly suggest squaring the input by multiplying it by itself, especially since it is an integer, and the answer is (apparently) expected to fit in an integer.  `ans = in * in;`

Comment: Carefully reproducing error message is a **key prerequisite** to getting good answers. You wouldn't be satisfied with an answer like "there must be a library missing or something like that" would you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

This type of error occur when you forgot to link your programme to the math library .
use `-lm` for linking to math library.

`gcc yourfilename.c -lm`

to use the math library

Answer (score 0):

I think you have compiled on Linux platform. So, use `-lm` option with command.

```
gcc yourfile.c -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `scans` instead of `scanf`. It should `scanf("%d",&in);`

Comment: Right..but that's probably a typo....