How do I force gcc to call memcpy under -Os
Under -Os, gcc likes to inline memcpy into rep movsb (x86-64).
How can I make it actually call memcpy while keeping the -Os compiler option?
Is there anything more local than -fno-builtin-memcpy that makes it do that?
I would prefer something I could do from inside a C file and something which generates a direct call (calling memcpy through a volatile pointer also succeeds in preventing inlining, but it does not generate a direct call).
https://godbolt.org/z/EjYbPaGzf

Why do you need that?

Try #undef memcpy?

@CherryDT I want that because I like control and because in a particular context of interest, I'm measuring glibc's memcpy as over 3 times as fast as the inlined rep movsb.

GCC pragmas allow you to push and pop options for specific sections of code. Gimme a sec to look it up...

@Barmar It's not a macro. Memcpy and similar functions are effectively compiler builtins backed by real library functions.

@Dúthomhas -fno-builtin.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062430/how-can-i-get-the-gcc-compiler-to-not-optimize-a-standard-library-function-call

You can enable -fno-builtin-memcpy, add #define memcpy(a,b,c) __builtin_memcpy((a),(b),(c)), and #undef selectively.

I wonder if calling the function through a pointer would work too?

@PetrSkocik But I thought it implemented this internally using a macro to replace it with an internal name of the built-in.

@Dúthomhas Not really :(, you delete that volatile on that godbolt example (https://godbolt.org/z/EjYbPaGzf) , and you're back to rep movsb. Gcc's is "clever" like that :D.

Yeah, I figured the optimizer would probably figure it out. I’d imagine having to make a separate object file that gets compiled without the optimization and a little trampoline to call would work...

@n.m.couldbeanAI  Thanks. I guess that should do it. I wasn't really trying to avoid -fno-builtin-memcpy per se, as I was trying to avoid having a different option for a particular file. I'm fine if I have -fno-builtin-memcpy everywhere. Will upvote and probably accept if you post it as an answer.

@Dúthomhas Thanks. I think I might do something like that. That  memcpy_wrapper: jmp memcpy is a wee bit of indirection but much better than the volatile-pointer stuff. :)

@PetrSkocik What about just calling memcpy_s()?  (The only useful part of Annex K....)  That's not listed in the GCC built-in functions here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html  FWIW, neither is memmove(), which might also be worth testing.

@AndrewHenle I don't quite know how to get memcpy_s to work on gcc and I've never used those _s functions, but memmove`` works great! Nicely calls into libc, and for my situation (copying page-sized buffers) I'm getting the same peformance as for memcpy. Thank you and everybody in the comments. Those have been great ideas.

The following:
__attribute__((__optimize__("O2")))
void *my_memcpy2(void *d, void *s, size_t c){
    return memcpy(d,s,c);
}

Outputs on godbolt:
my_memcpy2:
        jmp     memcpy


Yeah that's basically the non-inline wrapper idea (breaks down when made inline) with the nice simplification that it doesn't require a separate translation unit. A teensy bit of negligible-cost tailcall indirection. I will accept. Thanks!
