# <math.h> undefined references Native Android Activity VS 2019

Tags: c++, math, android-ndk, linker

If you create a new Native Android Application (or OpenGLES Project template), include , and use any of the math functions included with it (powf, ldexpl, sqrt, etc...) then you get an undefined reference to that method.

Another user had the same issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/188213/android-mathh-not-compiling-with-llvm-libc-in-vs20.html), but their solutions did not work for me.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: And have you added `-lm` to your libs?

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.  Is there a reference somewhere that mentions the '-lm' command?

Comment: Well this is a common library to be included when using math library. For a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#c_library tells you there is a separate libm "(following the usual Unix tradition), but like libc this is automatically linked by the build systems."

Comment: Maybe I have been spoiled by Visual Studio C++ projects because I've never had to link anything to use a math library in my 10 years of programming.