# Gcc doesn't recognise 'double complex' decleration

Tags: c, gcc

I need a complex library for some stuf in c++ or c.

So I found some useful tooltip in linux.

```
man complex
```

documentation have good example like this:

```
#include <math.h>        /* for atan */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int
main(void)
{
   double pi = 4 * atan(1.0);
   double complex z = cexp(I * pi);
   printf("%f + %f * i\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
}
```

everything goes well...

But I took error every time which I tried.

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g '/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2.cpp' -o '/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2' <

/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2.cpp:10:17: error: expected initializer before ‘z’
   10 |  double complex z = cexp(I * pi);
      |                 ^
/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2.cpp:11:32: error: ‘z’ was not declared in this scope
   11 |  printf("%f + %f * i\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
      |                                ^
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', '/usr/bin/g++ -g '/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2.cpp' -o '/home/max/Documents/c_expls/test2''" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I edited code a little bit, like adding `double complex z` etc.. but same machine... same error...

I think my gcc installation have lacks component. beause I tried Code::Blocks

Do you have an idea,
why my gcc doesn't know this declaration?

Comment: This is a `C` program, try to compile it with `gcc` not `g++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against the math library with the flag `-lm`

Using exactly your code in a file called test.c I compiled with:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lm
```

Running the binary gives the output:

```
./test
-1.000000 + 0.000000 * i
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with `gcc` and specify that you want to use the C99 standard or higher `-std=c99`.

For C++, use `std::complex`.

Comment: Thanks  for ans. I apricieted.Yeah I am trying some combinations of declaration almos none of them working except '__complex__ double z' it is only accept this type of decleration. _using namespace std::complex_literals;
std::complex<double> z;_ btw I checked with 'gcc -std=c17 test2.c -o test2' but gives error which 'test2.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `cexp''

Comment: @maxemilian: Add `-lm` to the end of your command line to link the math library.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c.  This is also noted on the Linux man page for `cexp`.  When using this, your code compiles and runs just fine for me.