# why sqrtf doesn't accept a variable as argument in debian or ubuntu?

Tags: c, gcc

I want work with this function and it will take a variable as argument but is not working with me. If i put the number it works but a number in argument does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  float x;
  x = 7;
  printf("%f", sqrtf(x)); // produces error "undefined reference to `sqrtf'"
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
   printf("%f", sqrtf(7)); // works
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Did you link in the math library, i.e. the `-lm` option to gcc?

Comment: no ididnt actually it is should just compile like this ```gcc -lm .c```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `sqrtf(7)` is evaluated compile time and `sqrtf` function is not called. (it "works")
2. `sqrtf(x)` is evaluated run time and `sqrtf` function is called. (it does not "work" - ie it does not link)
   [image]
   https://godbolt.org/z/oY6zfqxd1

You need to add `-lm` compile option to link against the math library. If you do not, the program will not link.

Comment: @AitbelhajAyoub Also, if you're feeling adventuresome, file a bug report with your compiler vendor.  You should not (IMHO) need to explicitly specify `-lm` to get a standard library function.

Comment: @SteveSummit did you fill the gcc bugzilla error report? :)

Comment: No, but I really should, since I complain/whine/flame about the issue enough.

Comment: Read [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033898/10077).

Comment: its work my brother thank you so mush  @0___________