# Printing prime number

Tags: c, for-loop, math

// Print all prime numbers from 1 to given number

> C Programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void checkprime(int);

int main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter the number till which you want prime numbers: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &num);

    checkprime(num);

    return 0;
}

void checkprime(int num)
{
    int flag, i, j;
    flag = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
         for (j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
             if (i % j == 0)
             {
                 flag = 0;
                 break;
             }

         if (flag)
             printf("%d\t", i);
         else
             printf("Not a prime number");
     }
}
```

// Output

```
Enter the number till which you want prime numbers: 10
```

It is showing build with errors and there is nothing in the output. I am not able to find the error.

The expected output should be all prime numbers form 1 to a given number, but there is nothing in the output.

I am new to C, so if you have any tips for me it will be helpful.

Comment: Please add code and errors to your question as text.

Comment: ooo sorry for that, let me modify it..

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the scanf format string. It is waiting for you to input a second non-whitespace character because of that. [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: _It is showing build with errors.._ a linker error perhaps? You need to link in the math library with `-lm` in order to use the `sqrt` function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Comment: @ArpitSingh `sqrt()` not needed. Replace `j <= sqrt(i);` --> `j <= i/j;`.

Comment: @ArpitSingh Move `flag = 1;` inside the `for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)` loop.

Comment: *It is showing build with errors*. Show us the errors please.

Comment: Read about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). This is a beautiful and simple method of finding all prime numbers up to a predetermined value very quickly.

Comment: It's probably best to start the `i` loop at 2 since mathematicians generally agree that 1 is not a prime.