# How to refresh the file math.h

Tags: c, gcc, math.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Am I Getting Link Errors When Calling Function in Math.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103407/why-am-i-getting-link-errors-when-calling-function-in-math-h)

Hello, I have a problem in C (gcc), when I compile a program that includes Math.h and uses functions from there, it says "undefined reference to...". it happens for sqrt, log, but for others not (for instance pow). How can I fix this library or reinstall it ? thanks in advance. 
[I am using Ubuntu]

Answer (score 2):

You shold link with -lm option: `gcc -o test test.c -lm` lm means link math.

Comment: actually -lname means link to library name. m is the math library.

Comment: actually `-lname` means to link against a library named `libname.so` or `libname.a` in that order