# pow() isn't defined

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int i, diff, sum = 0, num1 = 6, num2 = 2;

    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        diff = num1 - num2;
        sum += pow(diff, i);
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Whenever I am trying to execute this program, an error message just pops up saying:

> In function `main`:
>   undefined reference to `pow`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103407/why-am-i-getting-link-errors-when-calling-function-in-math-h

Comment: @meagar "exterminate" seemed too harsh

Comment: It works as written for me with gcc 4.6.1 on Mac OSX.  Prints out "341".  What compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: I hope you don't actually code like what you pasted in. FTFY.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a linker failure. You need to link with the math library, specify `-lm` at the end of your compiler command. From [man pow](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow):

> Link with -lm.

Answer (score 6):

Math library is not part of libc. You need to link it:

```
gcc file.c -lm -o file
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `pow()` is defined in the math library. Your compiler by default is not linking your program with that library as a result of which the linker is unable the resolve the call to `pow()`.

To fix this you need to add `-lm` at the end of your compile/link line which links the math lib to your program.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the same program on my Turbo C and i got output as 341. Check whether your header files are in place in /include folder of your Turbo C folder. Make sure to check whether it contains a Math.h file.