# undefined reference to a c built in function 'pow'

Tags: c, math.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pow() isn’t defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802185/pow-isnt-defined)

```
void octal2decimal(char *octal, char *decimal) {
int oct = atoi(octal);
int dec = 0;
int p = 0;

while (oct!=0) {

    dec = dec + (oct%10) * pow(8,p++); //since oct is base 8 
    oct/=10;
}
*decimal = (char)dec;
*/
}
```

For the following code above I get this error I dont know why I include `math.h` but still i get this errors

`/tmp/cck07bLe.o: In function 'octal2decimal':`
`data-converter.c:(.text+0x35f): undefined reference to 'pow'`
`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

What does it mean? and how can I fix it?

Comment: What command are you using to compile your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pow` is defined in the math library (`libm`), which isn't linked in by default. Thus, you should add  `-lm` to your compilation command to get the math library. For example, if you are using `gcc`:

```
gcc data-converter.c -o data-converter -lm
```

By the way, `pow` is not the right way to compute an integral power of two. You should instead use a shift:

```
dec += (oct%10) << (3*p++);
oct /= 10;
```

Shifting left by `3*p` is equivalent to multiplying by 8<sup>p</sup>, but avoids floating point numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Math library is not part of the standard C library which is included by default.
Link with the math library:

```
gcc file.c -o file -lm
```