# Error: Conflicting types for 'pow' in C

Tags: c, function, conflict, pow

The program is supposed to get letters both uppercase and lowercase from user and each letter is assigned to a value.

Example. S is 0, K is 1 and E is 2.
The totalvalue formula is ((A*10)+(B))*10^C

A - first input B - 2nd input C is the 3rd input.
The function `int lettervalue(char letter)` is supposed to return the value of the letter.
I used switch construct for assigning the letter value.

Everytime i compile I get `error: conflicting types for 'pow'`. Does the pow function accept variables, and is there something I should change in function `int lettervalue(char letter)`?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

int pow(int x, int y);

int lettervalue(char letter)
{
    int val;
    switch (letter){
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            val = 0;
            break;
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
            val = 1;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            val =2;
            break;
    }
    return val;
}

int main(void)
{   int valueA, valueB, valueC, totalvalue;
    char A, B, C;
    printf("Please input the letter: ");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &A, &B, &C);                
    valueA = lettervalue(A)*10;
    valueB = lettervalue(B);
    valueC = lettervalue(C);
    totalvalue = (valueA+valueB)*pow(10, valueC);
    printf("The total value is %d", totalvalue );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a signature for a library function?  Isn't that (part of) what .h files are for?

Comment: signature? do you mean 'int pow(int x, int y);' in the beginning, if i remove that i got 'undefined reference to pow'

Comment: @honmayanranger Did you remove `#include <math.h>` or `int pow(int x, int y);` or both?  You should only remove `int pow(int x, int y);` and _keep_ `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: Minor: Use `int val = 0;` in `lettervalue()` to deal with `letter` values that are not SsKkEe.

Comment: @chux removed int pow(int x, int y); only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code unnecessarily provides a `pow()` prototype, which is inconsistent with the one in `math.h`.

```
#include <math.h>
// math.h provides: double pow(double x, double y);
```

Eliminate `int pow(int x, int y);`.

Change code

```
// totalvalue = (valueA+valueB)*pow(10, valueC);
totalvalue = (valueA+valueB)* ((int)pow(10, valueC));
```

Or

```
double total;
total = (valueA+valueB)*pow(10, valueC);
printf("The total value is %.0lf", total );
```

---

Be sure to link in the math library to avoid 'undefined reference to pow'.

["undefined reference to `pow'" even with math.h and the library link -lm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344445/im-using-math-h-and-the-library-link-lm-but-undefined-reference-to-pow-st)

Comment: @honmayanranger After you get 15+ reputation, consider up voting _all_ the posts you found useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you already use math.h, you don't need to declare function pow. So removing line `int pow(int x,int y);` should help.

If you want to create your own simple pow function you don't need to add the library math.h, and define function pow as follows:

```
int pow(int x, int y)
{
  int result=1,i;
  for(i=1;i<=y;i++)
    result *=x;

  return result;
}
```

p/s: as the pow function grow very quickly, I suggest you use `long` value instead of `int`

Comment: This worked too but there is warning: conflicting types for pow[enabled by default], but it returned the same value. Thanks :)

Comment: did you exclude the library math.h when defining your pow function? Alternatively you can simply define it with different name such as  int power(int x,int y)

Answer (score 1):

The `pow()` function is defined in `math.h` as:

```
double pow (double base, double exponent);
```

The prototype your using for `pow()` makes confliction between arguments types as you changed them to `int`. You couldn't change the input and output types this way. You simply do it by casting the arguments and the returned value but this is not necessery as the conversion is done implicitly.

Just remove the `pow()` prototype.

Comment: removing it the compiler displays unknown reference to pow

Comment: @honmayanranger You might need to link to the math library. edd the `-lm` flag when linking your program..

Comment: @honmayanranger the math library is not linked.