# C - undefined reference to "sqrt" even with '-lm'

Tags: c, gcc, ld, math.h

I try to compile a library in C that need "math.h", here is the begining of the .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include "sparse_matrix.h"
...
```

and I compile with this command:

```
gcc -c ./sparse_matrix.c -o sparse_matrix.o -lm -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -g -O
```

But even with the `#include` done and the flag `-lm` after the file (I've tried at the end of the line but nothing changed) I still get the error:
    `undefined reference to « sqrt » 
     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I don't get it after an hour of googling the issue.
I'm working with gcc 4.9 under ubuntu 14.10 (utopic unicorn).
Thank for any help in advance!

Comment: The `-c` option suppresses linking.  You won't get that error from that command line.  Therefore, that isn't the command line that produces the error.  (Don't use @ before rules in a `makefile` — it probably isn't your problem, but it hides commands and can mislead you.)  And most of this is what @paxdiablo said.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to \`pow'" even with math.h and the library link -lm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344445/undefined-reference-to-pow-even-with-math-h-and-the-library-link-lm)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that *is* the command you're running (well, it may be *one* of them, but it's certainly not the one causing your error).

The `-c` option to `gcc` tells it to only create the object files (and you're specifically sending the output to `sparse_matrix.o`, an object file rather than an executable one).

In that case, the linker should *not* be called at all.

In fact, with a dummy `sparse_matrix.c` of:

```
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    return (int)(sqrt(16.0));
}
```

your command works fine and, when I complete the process with:

```
pax> gcc -o sparse_matrix sparse_matrix.o -lm
pax> ./sparse_matrix
pax> echo $?
4
```

you can see that it also runs just fine.

It may be that you're leaving off the linker flags (such as `-lm`) from the actual *link* stage, which would cause this problem. They should have no effect on the compilation stage (unless they affect both compile *and* link stages but `-l` isn't one of those).

And, by "leaving off", I also include the possibility of "misplacing". Some linkers are *positional* in the way they handle libraries in that they will only extract objects from libraries if they satisfy an undefined symbol *at the point where they're listed.*

So, the command:

```
linker sparse_matrix.o -lm ...
```

would work because the `.o` file introduces an unsatisfied reference to `sqrt`, which is satisfied by `libm`. If your linker *is* positional, then:

```
linker -lm sparse_matrix.o ...
```

wouldn't work because, at the time of processing `libm`, there were *no* unsatisfied symbols so nothing was extracted. The undefined reference to `sqrt` is then introduced *after* that point and there are no other objects or libraries to satisfy it.

Whether `ld` or the `gcc` linker stage has that limitation, I don't know, I'm just raising the possibility as something to watch out for.

Comment: Thank! In fact with the '-c' flag the linker is not called at all, it was a mistake. But I tried without the -c flag (gcc sparse_matrix.c -o sparse_matrix.o  -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -g -O -lm). But I've got an undefined reference to "main". As I said I only try to do a library "sparse_matrix" that need "sqrt" function from "libmath".

Comment: @Alex, check if there actually _is_ a `main` in that C file. Given you're separating compilation from link stages, it's likely that it exists in _another_ C file. If you're _only_ creating a library with objects (no `main`), `-c` is the way to go, but the bringing in of the math lib is something that should be done during linking, when a client of yours needs to use your stuff: `gcc client_stuff.c -lsparse_matrix_lib -lm ...`.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do. Thank, I'm not that ease with library and I thought I could link a lib into another. Sorry for this rather simple mistake. I just tried with my main program which use this library and (now that I understand that) it work fine (just added '-lm' NOT at the compilation time of the library but at the linking stage of the program using my lib) :) Thank again for such quick answers!