# Link math library with binfmtc

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using [binfmtc](https://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/binfmtc.html.en) to allow me to run a C program without performing an explicit build step.  This worked fine until I started using math functions, at which point I see messages such as:

> undefined reference to `sin'

The header that I use is:

```
/*BINFMTC: -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -lm
*/
```

How can I get this program to link?

Closely related: ["undefined reference to `pow'" even with math.h and the library link -lm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16344445/86967)

Comment: If you try to compile it with gcc, it compiles? is math lib reachable?

Comment: @LPs: Yes.  I can compile with gcc manually -- that lets me put '-lz' at the end of the full gcc command line, which `binfmtc` apparently does not.

Comment: Does `binfmtc` honor `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`?. If so, you can set `LDFLAGS="-lm -lz"`

Comment: @alvits: Good idea, but setting `LDFLAGS` has no effect.

Comment: Note: This problem is unique to 'C' -- it doesn't happen in C++ mode: `BINFMTCXX`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't elegant, but it works:

Create a wrapper script `gcclm.sh` for the library:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
gcc $@ -lm
```

Invoke the C program using the wrapper:

```
GCC=$(pwd)/gcclm.sh ./myprogram.c
```