# make doesn't link math lib when compiling

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I get the following error while compiling xpdf using `make`. I've tried using the command:

`LIBS=-lm make`

However, it doesn't work. I know the problem is that the c compiler cannot recognise the math symbols in the source code because the math library is not available to it, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable pdftohtml 
    /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xpdf_objs.dir/Gfx.cc.o: undefined reference to symbol 'acos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
    //usr/lib64/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [xpdf/CMakeFiles/pdftohtml.dir/build.make:219: xpdf/pdftohtml] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:428: xpdf/CMakeFiles/pdftohtml.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I have put my [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/hFCR77Ts) and [makeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/3cFJLS1Y) on pastebin for more information

Comment: What's  `-l make`? The compiler should have passed `-lm` to link the math library

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344445/undefined-reference-to-pow-even-with-math-h-and-the-library-link-lm) may be others are better.

Comment: @Eugene Sh, apologies. I've now corrected it to `-lm`. @Weather Vane It's not a duplicate, I've read several posts and tried their answers but none of them worked for me.

Comment: @weather: xpdf is written in C++ and there is no need to link C++ programs against `-lm`; it is supposed to be automatic.

Comment: @rici thank you, I did say other previous Qs could be better. Any suggestions?

Comment: @weather i can't find a better q and i'm in a cafe w/o a laptop. To me it feels like a glibc version mismatch where some DSO was compiled against an old glibc. (2.2.5? Rly?)

Comment: @rici. I used gcc as the compiler rather than g++. Maybe thats why `-lm` wasn't linked automatically

Comment: @mywrath: yes, if you are linking a c++ project, you should use g++ to get the right link options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I had to use the g++ compiler instead of gcc after reading the man page for gcc which stated:

> The usual way to run GCC is to run the executable called gcc, or
>   machine-gcc when cross-compiling, or machine-gcc-version to run a
>   specific
>          version of GCC.  When you compile C++ programs, you should invoke GCC as g++ instead.